# HOA0901 Wheel Encoder Circuit

Tags: encoder

I am trying to use the wheel encoder mentioned in the circuit but somehow i can't manage to understand why there is a full voltage drop in the IR led and why the resistors are not limiting that voltage drop, considering that in "ohmic" terms my circuit should work.

I would like somebody to help me pin what i am doing wrong

The datasheet is
http://sensing.honeywell.com/index.php?ci_id=50399

In the electric characteristics the datasheet says that the forward voltage should be 1.6 V@20mA and the supply of detector should be between 4.5 and 5.5V@7mA

So to use the resistors i have at hand the circuit is in the following attachment. For the IR led i connected it to a 5V source with a 220hm resistor and to the receiver 47 + 47 Ohm resistors.

Also i am connecting the A and B channel outputs to an atmega328 directly as the datasheet says the HOA0901 has internal pullups. I also set the atmga328p in input mode.

[image: My design]
Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "full voltage drop"? What is the *actual* voltage and where are you measuring it between?

Comment: By full voltage drop i mean that the voltage measured across the IR LED is 5V and i think shouldn't be, because i wanted it to be 1.6V

Comment: Okay - what is the voltage measured across the resistor (R5)?

Comment: 0V across it. I think that it is possible that the LED is not receiving enough current to saturate no?

Comment: Aha, thought so - it looks like you have blown your LED (it is open circuit)

Comment: Also, are you sure you are using a 220 Ohm resistor as in your schematic? I ask as in your text above the schematic you mention a 22 Ohm resistor. This would not be healthy for the LED ;-)

Comment: Oh darn. I miswired the first time and it probably was that. Otherwise does the circuit have any wrong value? The Resistor is indeed 220 Ohm as in the schematic

Comment: I can't seem to open the datasheet link so I can't be sure. From another [link](http://neil.fraser.name/hardware/gray2dir/In3eng.pdf) I googled it looks like you don't need the 47 Ohm resistors for the receiver, just apply 5V directly.

Comment: So do you want to give the answer that the ir led is fried for me to accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are measuring 0V across your resistor, then it looks like your LED is blown (open circuit)

V / R = I, so 0V * 220 = 0mA. This means there must be a high impedance in series with the resistor (i.e. open circuit LED)